# Present a view controller without scaling back existing content?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS app in which I present a view controller in order to display a full-screen advertisement. This is my `GameViewController`.

When I present `GameViewController`, the existing content is automatically pushed back a bit, away from the user (scaled down, I suppose). **I'd like to have the existing content stay in place *without* scaling back.**

To present `GameViewController`, I first grab the root view controller, like this:

```
let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.rootViewController
```

I then call `present` on the root view controller, passing in `GameViewController` as the first argument, like this:

```
rootViewController?.present(self, animated: false) {
   //Load the advertisement.
}
```

I tried experimenting with the `modalPresentationStyle` property, like this:

```
rootViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
```

**Question:** How can I stop the existing content from being scaled down/pushed away from the user when presenting a view controller?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of ***presenting*** it, load it as a Child View Controller and add its view as a subview to your existing view hierarchy. You can animate it in or display it any way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try tis:

```
let controller = GameViewController()
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**EDIT after your comment**

try that:

```
let controller = GameViewController()
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5) // or you can set it in your destination controller
present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This is great. The key is setting `modalPresentationStyle` on `GameViewController` instead of on the root view controller. One thing: the root view controller (the existing content) goes totally black...is there a way to just have a partially transparent overlay over the existing content instead?